# Add click listener to gwt's Grid row

Tags: gwt, grid, onclicklistener

Is it possible to add a ClickHandler to the whole row of gwt's Grid object? It is possible to add a ClickHandler to the whole grid but how can I determine which exactly row was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on GWT version, you might be able to use:

```
public HTMLTable.Cell getCellForEvent(ClickEvent event)
```

The Cell has a `getRowIndex()` method.